# How to get a list of all postgres clusters built with initdb?

Tags: postgresql, clustering

I understand that, to get a list of clusters with `pg_lscluster` I need to use tools like `pg_createcluster`.

But, I use `initdb` and `pg_ctl` to create clusters. I know they are running because I can access each cluster (I have three clusters) with `psql -p [port]`.

How do I get a list of clusters built with these tools?

Comment: `pg_lsclusters` searches the directories under `/etc/postgresql` to find the configuration of the clusters there. If you don't have your cluster configuration there, `pg_lsclusters` won't find the cluster.

Comment: Right. I was away of that. Which is why I am asking about `initdb`, not pg_lsclusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've created clusters using `initdb` and manage them with `pg_ctl`, they wont appear in the output of `pg_lsclusters` because `pg_lsclusters` specifically looks for clusters managed by the `pg_createcluster` tool.

You can still find info about the clusters you've created using `initdb` and `pg_ctl` by looking in the PostgreSQL data directory and configs.

Within the path to your PostgreSQL data directory there are subdirectories named after the PostgreSQL version and cluster names.

Within each data directory, there's a `postgresql.conf` files.

```
cat /var/lib/postgresql/<PostgreSQLversion>/<cluster_name>/postgresql.conf | grep "cluster_name"
```

Will show all the info about the cluster

Comment: Got it. Interestingly the cluster names and the ports of the clusters I created are commented out. And have the default port in the comment. I am a bit confused how my clusters work when the configs are commented like this.

Comment: Commenting out those lines simply means that the default values are being used. PostgreSQL will still function correctly because it has sensible default configurations that it can rely on if specific settings are not provided in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

`initdb` or `pg_ctl` do not maintain any system-wise list. The cluster directory can be created (or subsequently moved) to a completely arbitrary location at the discretion of the administrator. Configuration files can also be anywhere. These utilities simply do what they are told to do.

Search for them as usual for unknown server:

- check in the server documentation what to look for where
- ask other administrators on the team
- look at the list of processes and listening ports to see which network services are running. Connect to postgresql and check where it is located using `show data_directory;`

`pg_createcluster` (and `pg_lscluster`, `pg_ctlcluster`) are Ubuntu/Debian-specific wrappers around `initdb` and `pg_ctl` precisely for the purpose of providing a simpler interface for managing multiple postgresql instances on the same host. For example, a list of clusters.